# How do Hide / Show DIV's based on Div ID Content

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically displayed content in DIVS,  and I want to block certain DIVS from appearing.  The code looks like this:

```
 <div class = "DivStyle" id="computer">
  <img src = "computer,jpg">
 </div>

 <div class = "DivStyle" id="harddisk">
  <img src = "harddisk.jpg">
 </div>

 <div class = "DivStyle" id="cable">
  <img src = "cable.jpg">
 </div>
```

etc.

How can I block the div tabled "harddisk" above from appearing using Javascript?  Essentially I want to say "If ID = harddisk then display=none".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using jquery, simple: `$('img[src="harddisk.jpg"]).parent().hide();`. with bare js, not quite as simple but same concept. get all imgs, loop over them, check src attribute, then hide parent node.

Comment: @MarcB I think we're trying to hide based on the ID, not the image source.

Comment: then it's even simpler, `getElementById('harddisk').parentNode.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: I don't know how to use jQuery.  Could you post an example?  And where would I add the code? In side the HEAD of the page,  or within the div /div of the html?  Sorry for the dumb questions. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using plain javascript, this will hide your div:

```
document.getElementById('harddisk').style.display = "none";
```

A full example of where to locate the javascript:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class = "DivStyle" id="computer">
      <img src = "computer,jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "DivStyle" id="harddisk">
      <img src = "harddisk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "DivStyle" id="cable">
      <img src = "cable.jpg">
    </div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('harddisk').style.display = "none";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it though but it does not work.  I added your code inside a script tag in the head of the document,  but nothing changes.  Web inspector says "!Null is not an object' error too if this helps.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to run the javascript after the DOM has loaded.  It should work if you put it at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The script must be executed after the DOM is loaded, move the code inside this block, like this

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('harddisk').style.display = "none";
})();
```

if you are using an updatepabel use this one :

```
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(function () {
    document.getElementById('harddisk').style.display = "none";
});
```